# What is the reason routing in my project not works correctly?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I type `"/create"` after the address, I expect it shows `Home` component. Since I don't use from `exact` prop. Because `path='/c'` matches with `"/create"`, but it shows `Create` component. It first worked fine and when I used from `exact` prop it worked fine as expected. I don't know why it does not work as expected after I removed `exact` from the first `Route`.

It works fine only if I do: `<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />`

**Note: I used this for run server:** `npx json-server --watch data/db.json --port 8000`

See that on Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-feather-uz2iur

It's the section of my Routes:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="content">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/c" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/create" element={<Create />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

It gives the same result on my Webstorm(react-router-dom version 5):

```
  <Router>
      <div className="App">
          <Navbar />
          <div className="content">
              <Switch>
                  <Route path="/">
                      <Home />
                  </Route>
                  <Route path="/create">
                      <Create />
                  </Route>
              </Switch>
          </div>
      </div>
  </Router>
```

Comment: what version are you using? I can provide a working example with version 5, not 6. I don't know what changed in version 6

Comment: @Apostolos I use version 5 on Webstorm. But it has the same result on Codesandbox I think uses version 6.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2):

It seems the issue is a misunderstanding of how route path matching changed from `react-router@5` to `react-router@6`.

In RRDv5 the route path was more of a "path prefix", meaning it behaved like you described. A `path="/c"` could match ***any*** URL path starting with `"/c"`. This had its peculiarities when trying to specifically, or exactly, match certain routes. This is often why naive devs would pepper ***all*** their routes with the `exact` prop (*because not understanding how matching worked*).

For example, your v5 version, it would need to use the `exact` prop in order to match `"/c"` exactly and render the `Home` component, or not match exactly so the `Create` component could be matched.

```
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Navbar />
    <div className="content">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/c" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/create" component={Create} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </div>
</Router>
```

This is because of (A) the way route matching works in v5, and (B) the way the `Switch` component renders ***only*** the first matching `Route` or `Redirect` component. The route path order and specificity matters! In almost 100% of the use cases you don't need the `exact` prop by simply ordering your routes correctly, from ***most specific*** to ***least specific***.

The same v5 routes and switch, but ordered correctly:

```
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Navbar />
    <div className="content">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/create" component={Create} />
        <Route path="/c" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Note now that `"/c"` can't match to `path="/create"` and matching continues down until it finds and matches `path="/c"`.

In RRDv6 paths are now ***always*** exactly matched, so the `exact` prop no longer exists as it's not needed. Each route uses a path ranking system, see [Ranking Routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#ranking-routes). The specificity of the path yields a rank value and this is used to match a route. Route order is now irrelevant.

```
<Routes>
  {/* match & render when path is exactly "/c" */}
  <Route path="/c" element={<Home />} />

  {/* match & render when path is exactly "/create" */}
  <Route path="/create" element={<Create />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the complete explanation:) But don't you know why it ignores the first route even when I don't use `exact`?(in version 5) Since `/c` must be matched with `/create`. In my case, only `/` matches with `/create`.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi Sorry, can you clarify what you think is being ignored?

Comment: I mean, why `/create` doesn't match to `path='/c'` and matching continues down and it shows `create` component. While I don't use an `exact` prop.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi It's because the RRDv6 code already exactly matches route paths by default. There isn't any `exact` prop.

Comment: Yes, it's right for RRDv6. But I say it for RRDv5. Because I use this version for my project.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi I still don't understand what you are asking for/about. Can you provide a running codesandbox of your code using RRDv5 that demonstrates the issue/question?

Comment: Now just if I type `/create` it matches to `path='/'`. But doesn't match to `path='/c'` or `path='/cr'` or etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245862/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-arman-ebrahimi).

Answer (score 1):

Using `react-router-dom` version 5 you can use `Switch` along with `*` and it should work

```
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Navbar />
    <div className="content"></div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/c*">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/create">
        <Create />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

According to documentation

> A `Switch` looks through all its children  elements and renders
> the first one whose path matches the current URL. Use a  any
> time you have multiple routes, but you want only one of them to render
> at a time

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-meadow-tqrmvj?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why it doesn't work with `path='/c'`? It worked at first and I don't know why now doesn't work.

Comment: i think `/c` works with context paths e.g. `/c/`, `/c/d`, `/c/d/e`. not 100% sure though

Answer (score 1):

There was a breaking change in v6 regarding "exact" prop - it does not exist anymore and all paths are by default exact.

You can read more here: [upgrading to v6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5)

> Route exact is gone. Instead, routes with descendant routes (defined
> in other components) use a trailing * in their path to indicate they
> match deeply

Comment: It has the same result in version 5 on my Webstorm.

Comment: Can you explain to me what exactly you are trying to do with you routes? I am not sure I fully understand you problem.

Comment: It's just a thing that isn't sense and I want to know why. I don't use `exact` in the first Route So I expect to see the Home component when I insert `/create` after the address. (on version 5)